# What was the main role of alcoholic drinks in ancient to medieval times?

Tags: ancient-history, middle-ages, alcohol

I assume that alcoholic drinks served two main purposes in centuries gone by:

1. To purify water for consumption
2. Drunkenness

I'm not clear on number one being the case, and if it is I'm not sure which played a more prominent role in drinking alcohol. Did most people drink alcohol to avoid getting sick, or were they just drunks like us?

Comment: Like *us*? So you blindly assume all other SE users are drunks?

Comment: I disagree that this is off-topic. The main role of alcohol *isn't* up for debate, it should have a well defined answer, even if that answer is 'there isn't a main role'

And Bregalad it was a joke alluding to modern societies mostly being alcohol abusers.

Comment: I sometimes come off as a little more abrasive than I intend.. not my intention at all, but for as long as I've been using the Stack Exchange platform I still have trouble adapting to many of the communities and understanding a lot of mod actions. But I guess we're all human.

Comment: No worries, I don't mind.

Comment: In the middle ages alcohol was food. If it was for example not provided in an army there would be complaints.

Comment: Also in ancient times wine diluted with water was a staple, often the only beverage considered safe to drink. This may have lead to some boisterous behaviour in places where good water was hard to come by. At the same time systemic overindulgence was frowned upon though as a sign of decadence.

Comment: I really don't think watering wine was for purifying the water. The alcohol level you need to purify water is around the max you can get with modern champagne yeast -- which has been bred to have high alcohol tolerance. I think it's much more likely that they watered wine for taste, and either had a tolerance for the local water or didn't think diarrhea was something worth mentioning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your thinking is overly binary. It is very possible, indeed likely, that it was likely a combination of the two plus a few other factors you are forgetting depending on place/time/occasion/society.

Other factors in alcohol use:

1. Culture
2. Taste
3. Preservation of foodstuff
4. Others

Comment: Makes sense. I guess the question then becomes 'how did alcohol originate'. Did somebody accidentally get drunk and have a eureka moment, or did it arise out of the need to purify water. After that point it would have just been.. happening because of a range of factors.

Comment: Alcohol originate independently at various periods of time in different parts of the globe. Due to the lack of scientific method, I think we can assume it was almost always discovered by accident (fermenting fruit would be a good source, see example of drunk animals discovering fermented fruits). Why it caught on is likely taste/fun/culture/Preservation of foodstuffs/Medicinal